# Action in Low Quality Posts Review Queue

Tags: discussion

The LQP review queue offers only three possible actions (other than skip): approve (OK as is), edit, or delete.  A good percentage of these posts are low quality as-is, but could be improved.  I frequently don't have the knowledge to edit it myself (also, if a post is in the LQP queue, it typically requires a level of edit that should only be performed by the OP because of the scope of change required).  But I can leave a comment about the nature of the fix needed, and the OP can edit it.  Sometimes they do.

To encourage new posters, it would be better to give them feedback and let them improve the post and learn, rather than immediately delete their first posts.  The LQP options are geared toward immediate resolution (fix now or delete), rather than a more user-friendly option of feedback now and delete later if it's still necessary (i.e., fourth action option of comment).

If a post is deleted and later improved, the OP needs to jump through hoops to get it undeleted, and that rarely happens.

In these cases now, I comment and then skip.  What is the preferred method of handling these?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, the preferred method is the method you sketch out:
if an answer (or any contribution for that matter) is low quality, it can/should be

- flagged as such;
- commented on to provide the user with helpful (and friendly) feedback;
- downvoted if so desired (but that might not feel very welcoming for the poster);
- left for the time being.

When encountered in the Low Quality queue, you can leave a comment so the OP knows what's wrong (and downvote), and pick 'Delete'.

I often wait for a day or so, and check the user's profile to see if they have been online ever since their initial interaction. If not, I'll usually go on and delete an answer if it's unsalvageable, and leave a comment so the user knows why that happened.
This might not be the most lenient amount of time, but I feel that if someone was genuinely interested in providing proper information and being part of our community, they will check back soon.

**It is not up to anyone else to improve posts of others if it means adding new information**, including relaying it from a link in the post!
**A low-quality post almost always can only be saved by the OP.**
Editing is for improving structure, phrasing, updating a picture of better quality, adding tags, and other steps that *only enhance the original information and intent*.

---

As with closed questions and even downvoted contributions, there is nothing wrong with deleted answers: it's just a way for others to improve the platform for everyone.
Maybe we should highlight this aspect on the Tour page, because it is hard to grasp this concept, especially for firstcomers, and currently there is no mention of it whatsoever.

---

VLQ flags have a kind of notoriety on SE.
Your question, for example, seems to reflect this one on Meta.SE:
[Insufficient options in the low-quality review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364394/insufficient-options-in-the-low-quality-review-queue) and [Can we have more options for low-quality reviews?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/364255/can-we-have-more-options-for-low-quality-reviews)
Little constructive feedback is offered there, but it does give additional pointers as to the nature of the Low Quality flag.

And finally, for completeness: [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/180029/422926) is the official Low Quality review item thread on Meta.SE.

Comment: what happens when I press "done"? does it marks it as solved and then no more people can go and check it as a task? is that why i should hit "skip"?

Comment: why is this a thing though, i mean, everyone should just have a time period to review the task, not only depending on one person but on every person that's active, no?

Comment: @Isaac750 There is no 'Done' option in the Low Quality review queue. And why is what a thing? Everyone has time to go through these queues, I'm not sure I know what you mean, can you explain?

Comment: ok:    I wasn't sure about how  the review queue works (see comment #1)I didn't know that everyone reviewed it until someone pressed the submit button(or whatever the button is called to mark it as done)         I just didn't know how it worked :p

Comment: There's an implication of clicking OK vs. skip, which also relates to @Isaac750's comments.  If I remember correctly and if it hasn't changed, posts stay in the LQP review queue until either of two things happen: 1.  I believe it's 2 or 3 reviewers vote that the post is OK, so it exists the review queue (the delete votes remain but age away), or 2. Sufficient reviewers vote to delete (believe it's 5), and the post is deleted.  On a small site with few reviewers, it can be hard to collect 5 delete votes.  (cont'd)

Comment: If a few reviewers vote OK (for now) on a post that might need deletion later, that can remove it from review and make it hard to delete later unless a moderator steps in.  Skipping leaves it in the queue, so it can be easier to delete if needed a day or two later if the post doesn't get improved.

Comment: @Isaac750, Skip indicates that you're taking no action at this time.  You can use that any time you aren't sure what to do with a particular post, or you're unfamiliar with the subject matter, or a case like covered in this question, where you intentionally want to delay taking action.  I forget the places Done is displayed.  I think it's for when you might potentially take multiple actions, like leave a comment plus select an action.  It's how to signify that you've completed everything you plan to do with the post.

Comment: @fixer1234 Good points, but as an alternative I suggest to click away from the queue: that way, it will stay in the queue as a reminder, and you can check back after a while to see if anything has changed, or it will disappear because other users or a mod have dealt with it. We are too small a community with too few active users for these items to be dealt with swiftly, I fear. As for the current numbers of votes required for items to disappear from the queue: I can't at the moment seem to find them, but you're either right, or the numbers are somewhat lower because of recent changes.